# TypeScript duplicate identifier error messages in Webstorm 11.0.3

Tags: webstorm

So, I've selected 'enable typescript compiler', v1.7.3 (bundled) in Webstorm 11.0.3, have babel enabled in Tools/File Watchers, and am receiving the following error messages:

`C:\Users\Theo\Documents\Projects\kit-typescript\jspm_packages\npm\typescript@1.7.5\lib\lib.core.d.ts
Error:(83, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'configurable'.
Error:(84, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'enumerable'.
Error:(85, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
Error:(86, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'writable'.
Error:(97, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'constructor'.
Error:(133, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
Error:(252, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
Error:(253, 5) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'length'.
etc etc`

I know that the issue is caused by Webstorm TS (1.7.3) compiler clashing with typescript in my jspm_packages/npm/typescript@1.7.5.

How do I get Webstorm to ignore typescript bundled in my project package? I've excluded the jspm_packages folder in my project window, but with no change.

The program runs properly when I launch it in the browser. I just want to get rid of duplicate error messages.

My tsconfig.json file is as follows:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
]
```

}

Many thanks

Comment: try adding jspm_packages to 'exclude' section in your tsconfig.json - does it help?